# Merging span CSS style with Schema

Tags: html, css

I prefer to use Microdata for some structured data.

Here is an example of some ultra-simple inline CSS I am using:

```
<span style="color:#e74c3c;">Name of Event</span>
```

And here is the Microdata span tag:

```
<span itemprop="name">Name of Event</span>
```

Is it ok to merge these two attributes like this:

```
<span style="color:#e74c3c;" itemprop="name">Name of Event</span>
```

Just want to be 100%

I can't test it because I have someone else checking the production site code w/out my suggesion...

Comment: Of course it is, why shouldn’t it be? (Whether you _should_ be using inline styling in the first place, would be a different question …)

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use the attribute as a selector in your stylesheet, so you don't even _have_ to use inline CSS: `span[itemprop='name'] {color:#e74c3c;}`

Answer (score 1):

@Mr Lister gave the best answer IMO - use attribute as a selector! Thanks